# Disable iOS "Perspective Compensation" programmatically?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

Maybe I'm just searching for the wrong term, but I've been able to find very little information on this subject, and I think it could be a problem for my app.

A while back, there was an article on the accuracy of the touch screens on iOS devices, and it seemed quite poor compared to other phones. Here is a link a posting about it:
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1660713

Anyway, many of the commenters referred to "perspective compensation" as a cause for the inaccuracy. Basically, they are saying that iOS intentionally registers touches above the actual point of contact to compensate for the typical viewing angle of the user or for the angle of their finger or something like that. I have found that there is some credibility to that claim myself by doing as one of the commenters suggested and trying to use my iPhone upside down. I did find that it was difficult to touch things in some cases, and I have also noticed this problem in one of the apps I'm developing.

**So, in case you want to skip all that rambling above, here is why it's a problem for me:**

I am developing an app that is intended to be used by two people at the same time. The iPhone or iPad is placed on a surface between two people who are sitting across from one another, and they are instructed to quickly and accurately touch items on their respective halves of the screen competitively. What the article's comments made me suspect might happen, and what I have also found in practice is that the person using the phone upside down will have trouble touching buttons and dots on their first try. I've also tested slowly with a stylus and found that the touchable area of a button does indeed extend below a button, or above the button for the person using the phone upside down, hence the discrepancy and problem/disadvantage for that person.

**So finally, if you want to skip that also, here is my question: Can "perspective compensation"(if that's what it's called) be disabled programmatically, and can it be done for specific views of an app? Have any of you noticed this and dealt with it in an app of yours?**

While I have found that "perspective compensation" does seem to be occurring, I have not found any official documentation of it, and therefore have no idea how or if it can be disabled. When I search for "perspective compensation," the only results I find are links to the same article and comments.

I can't help but expect that this may have been asked before or is solvable with a simple checkbox, but perhaps for lack of the correct term to use, I have been unable to find any leads.

Thanks in advance for any of your solutions or suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done with the current SDK. All we have access to is the touch location, which is at a single point. Other search terms you might try are "digitizer" or "raw touch data", but there is definitely no check box or simple option.

To implement this, you will have to compensate for the touch location yourself. You'll need to play around with a compensating offset value for the upside-down buttons. Hit testing on views is probably the best place to do this, then your buttons can just respond to events as normal.